# Using importxml in google script - unable to display content of xpath

Tags: xml, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I would like to get the contents of the beer menu displayed in this website:

https://untappd.com/v/titans-craft-beer-bar-and-bottle-shop/5286704

but when I use importxml I get a "could not fetch URL warning:

I tried
=importxml(A8, "//*[(@id='section_269017548')]//text()")

=importxml(A8, "//ul[@class='menu-section-list']/b/text()")
(where A8 is the URL of the page)

but I am not having luck..
Any advice on how to get all the

included in the ul class="menu-section-list" ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZymZJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHnTC.png)

Comment: About `I would like to get the contents of the beer menu displayed in this website:`, can you provide the values you want to retrieve?

Comment: hi there, thank you for your reply. I am trying to get the values of all the <li></li> contained in <ul class ="menu-section-list" id="section-menu-list269017548">
see this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZymZJ.png

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: No need to apologize, I am the one sorry for my lack of knowledge! So I am trying to get the 
the contents of the beer menu displayed in this website:

https://untappd.com/v/titans-craft-beer-bar-and-bottle-shop/5286704
if I inspect the site I can see that what I need is in "menu-section-list" id="section-menu-list-269780374"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHnTC.png
Does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I am the one sorry for my lack of knowledge! So I am trying to get the the contents of the beer menu displayed in this website: untappd.com/v/titans-craft-beer-bar-and-bottle-shop/5286704`, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected values. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output values you expect?

Comment: When you inspect the page, can you see the element with path:
//*[@id="section-menu-list-269780374"]

I'd like to get all the <li></li> that are containing the info of each beer,
see:
https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#4t5jzvm8qiispg0ma0n1wd

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: would that be ok if I send you a email to the email listed in your git repo? so I can explain more in details?